# Get days of the week on a series with DateTime Index

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am sure this is simple but...

I have a timestamped data which I convert to a data frame.  From there I resample the data I am interested in using the timestamp column.  This part works fine and the `resample()`  function gives me a series which has the date time object as  the index.

```
    fiveminbins = mydata['measurement'].resample('5min').sum()
```

giving

```
    Date
    2019-04-05 04:55:00+01:00    160
    2019-04-05 05:00:00+01:00      0
    2019-04-05 05:05:00+01:00      0
    2019-04-05 05:10:00+01:00      0
```

I now want to add days of the week, but for the life of me I can't get methods using either `DateTime.dayofweek` or `dt.dayofweek` to work on the index of this series. From the examples I've seen online I should be able to use

```
    fiveminbins.dt.dayofweek
```

but the returns
        AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

I've tried calling it on the index of the series specifically

```
    fiveminbins.index.dt.dayofweek

    AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

So I tried using DatetimeIndex.dayofweek

```
    fiveminbins.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek

    'Series' object has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'
```

and then on the index specifically

```
     fiveminbins.index.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek

     AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'
```

and so now I'm lost doing something I've done several times before, just not on the index of a column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to reset the index, enforce the column to be a datetime and it should work:

```
fiveminbins = fiveminbins.reset_index()
fiveminbins.Date = pd.to_datetime(fiveminbins.Date)
print(fiveminbins.Date.dt.dayofweek)
```